# Configuring a Power Mac as a Gateway

Tags: mac, firewall, osx-server

I have a Mac OS X Leapord Server v10.6.8 installed on an Xserve and currently have things set up in the following order:

```
ISP --> Router --> Switch --> Server --> iMac.
```

I also have a Power Mac G5 with OS X 10.5.8 configured as a server. I was wondering if it was possible to configure the PowerMac as a gateway, to serve as a firewall; blocking access from outside coming in

```
ISP --> Router --> Server --> Switch --> Server --> iMac
```

I had looked it up on the internet, but I could not find anything useful.

If it is possible:

- What are the advantages and disadvantages of configuring the machine as a gateway?
- How can it be accomplished?

Edited: Forgot to mention the main server. Also, I have already installed an ethernet card in addition to the ethernet port on the Power Mac.

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but depends on what you really *need*. Your router should take care of any unwanted external connections, therefore eliminating the need for a dedicated firewall. Also, note that you would need two ethernet connections on your Server then and it's (in my opinion) much harder to configure and maintain such a network setup.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the PowerMac as a makeshift firewall.

I'd recommend running either [IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org) or [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org) as the firewall/gateway management software.

Just make sure that you read up on the tutorials/guides available on the websites, and downlaod the correct ISO for your system's architecture. (PPC I suppose).